# Grafana + prometheus node-exporter data source error - Instant query faile(bigger context)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

My problem is that when I'm trying to connect to a data source that is node-exporter the following error pops up in the logs.

```
grafana                    | t=2021-12-31T07:37:52+0000 lvl=eror msg="Instant query failed" logger=tsdb.prometheus query=1+1 err="bad_response: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found <, error found in #1 byte of ...|<html>\n\t\t\t<|..., bigger context ...|<html>\n\t\t\t<head><title>Node Exporter</title></head>|..."
```

The same thing is happening for both node-exporters.

I'm using docker compose and docker containers to deploy prometheus, node-exporter and grafana but even without containers I was receiving the same error.

The prometheus is pulling metrics for all targets, and it looks like it's working fine.
[image: prometheus targets view]

My docker compose settings for node:

```
  node-exporter:
image: prom/node-exporter:latest
container_name: prometheus-node-rockwatch
restart: unless-stopped
ports:
  - "9100:9100"
volumes:
  - /proc:/host/proc:ro
  - /sys:/host/sys:ro
  - /:/rootfs:ro
command:
  - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
  - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
  - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
  - '--collector.filesystem.mount-points-exclude=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't need to add exporters as data sources to Grafana, you only need to add Prometheus.

Comment: thanks for that! I can see metrics for my nodes in grafana without node exporters in data source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586927/how-to-add-the-kafka-exporter-as-a-data-source-to-grafana